# Reset Password POST refreshing page without posting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a password reset form in which when the user clicks the link in their email, they are sent to a password reset page.

The password form is validated with [FormValidation](http://formvalidation.io/), but I am running into the issue where when the user submits, the page refreshes, clears the GET variables and doesn't enter into the `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')` section.

You can see the uploaded code [here](http://www.thelaunchpadsociety.com/reset_password.php?email=vudanthony@gmail.com&token=70efdf2ec9b086079795c442636b55fb).

I've tried various solutions but don't know whats wrong. Anything helps!

Thanks guys!

Here is my PHP code:

```
        // ERROR REPORTING
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        // END ERROR REPORTING


        if(isset($_GET['email']) && isset($_GET['token']))
           {
                //Get variables from email password reset link
                $token = $_GET ['token'];
                $email = $_GET['email'];
                require_once('dbconfig.php');

               //CHECK TO SEE IF EMAIL EXISTS IN THE DATABASE//
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM users_launchpad WHERE email = '$email' ";
                $query  = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
                if ($result['email'] == $email)
                {
                    $check1 = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    $check1=false;
                }
                //END EMAIL CHECK//

                //CHECKS TO SEE IF ID MATCHES TOKEN//
                if(md5($result['id'])==$token)
                {
                    $check2 = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    $check2 = false;
                }

                //END ID CHECK

                //IF BOTH CHECKS ARE TRUE, CHANGE PASSWORD UPON POST.
               if($check1==$check2)
                {    
                    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
                    {
                        $password = $_POST['password'];
                        $update_password = "UPDATE users_launchpad SET password = '$password' WHERE email = '$email'";
                        $password_query  = mysqli_query($conn, $update_password);
                         // header('location: reset_password_success.php');
                        if ($password_query)
                        {
                            $success_message = "Password Updated Successfully";   
                        }
                    }

                }

            } 



    ?>
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<?php require_once('header.php');?>
<link href='../css/login.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href ='../css/formValidation.min.css' type = 'text/css'>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "col-md-offset-4 col-md-4" id = "loginForm">
        <div class = "row">

//CREATE FORM
            <form role="form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" id = "reset_password">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Reset Password</legend>
                    <div class = "col-md-12 text-center ">
                        <span class="text-success "><?php if (isset($success_message)) {echo $success_message;} ?></span>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">New Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required class="form-control" />

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Confirm New Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" required class="form-control" />

                    </div>
                    </fieldset>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" name="reset_password" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>

            </form>
            <div class = "col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center">
                <span class="text-danger "><?php if (isset($errormsg)) { echo $errormsg;} ?></span>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="token" value= "" />
    </div>

//END CREATE FORM
```

Here is the Javascript:

```
//INCLUDE BOOTSTRAP AND FORM VALIDATION
    <script src="//oss.maxcdn.com/bootbox/4.2.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/formValidation.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/framework/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $('#reset_password')
            .formValidation({
            framework: 'bootstrap',
            icon: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields: {
                password: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Your password is required'
                        },
                            stringLength: {
                            min: 4,
                            max: 30,
                            message: 'Your password must be between 4 and 30 characters'
                        },
                            identical: {
                                field: 'confirmPassword',
                                message: 'The password and its confirm are not the same'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    confirmPassword: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Your password is required'
                        },
                            stringLength: {
                            min: 4,
                            max: 30,
                            message: 'Your password must be between 4 and 30 characters'
                        },
                            identical: {
                                field: 'password',
                                message: 'The password and its confirm are not the same'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        })


            .on('success.form.fv', function(e) 
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                var $form = $(e.target);
                $form.get(0).submit();
                return false;

            });
    });
    </script>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PHP code you need to send email and set token as i can see token is being not sent  **in request only password and confirmPaswword is being sent** .

1- Place token inside form.

2- Make form view as PHP page to send email as hidden.

```
//CREATE FORM
        <form role="form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" id = "reset_password">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Reset Password</legend>
                <div class = "col-md-12 text-center ">
                    <span class="text-success "><?php if (isset($success_message)) {echo $success_message;} ?></span>
                </div>
                <br>
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">New Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required class="form-control" />

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Confirm New Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" required class="form-control" />

                </div>
                </fieldset>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" name="reset_password" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
                   <input type="hidden" name="token" value= "random" />
                                         <input type="hidden" name="email" value= <?= $_GET['email'] />
        </form>
        <div class = "col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center">
            <span class="text-danger "><?php if (isset($errormsg)) { echo $errormsg;} ?></span>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>

</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, 
An email is sent in via the "Forgot Password" webpage. The Forgot Password webpage will send an email with the user email and token. Once that link is clicked, it gets redirected to this page where they can reset their email and password. 

The other webpage can be viewed here:
http://thelaunchpadsociety.com/forgot_password_action.php

The issue is that the original post resets the email and token on post and somehow clears the users new password POST

Comment: But when password reset form is submitted you need to know in for which email the password is being changed. So you need to send email too .

Comment: Yes, email is sent via the variables inside the hyperlink:

 http://www.thelaunchpadsociety.com/reset_password.php?email=vudanthony@gmail.com&token=70efdf2ec9b086079795c442636b55fb

In this case, the email is my email "vudanthony@gmail.com" and the token is my md5(id) which is requested from mysql server

I use the php $_GET['email'] and $_GET['token'] to retrieve the variables from the hyperlinks so I know which email to change

Comment: I am saying second time when user fills password reset form. The php code will not work as form is being sent as POST and you have condition if(isset($_GET['email']) && isset($_GET['token'])) which will not fulfill as not being sent email and token see  in network tab request .

Comment: I am posting an image to show how request is going.

Comment: Got it! Thanks! I would like to edit for future usersthat the following lines of code need slight revision for proper syntax:

<input type="hidden" name="token" value= "<?= $_GET['token']" />
<input type="hidden" name="email" value= <?= "$_GET['email'] "/>
        </form>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121449/discussion-between-abhishek-chaurasia-and-anthony-vu).